# The $scope variable is undefined unless I forced it to retrieve from service again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

Here is the code snippet about an Angular Controller. I'm trying to learn Angular from this [github project](https://github.com/diegonetto/stk-decomposed/blob/master/step-5/app/scripts/controllers/watchlist.js)

The questionable part is located in function ***addStock***. I have already defined $scope.watchlist in the initilizations part, however, if I remove the re-declaration inside ***$scope.addStock*** function, $scope.watchlist will not be populated with right values. Can any Angular experts point me out? 
If you want to see my full project code - here is the [link](https://github.com/CatLovesPurple/StockCat/tree/master/app).

```
angular.module('stockCatApp')
  .controller('WatchlistCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $modal, WatchlistService, CompanyService) {
    // Initializations
    $scope.companies = CompanyService.query();
    $scope.watchlist = WatchlistService.query($routeParams.listId);
    $scope.stocks = $scope.watchlist.stocks;
    $scope.newStock = {};
    var addStockModal = $modal({
      scope: $scope,
      template: 'views/templates/addstock-modal.html',
      show: false
    });

    $scope.showStockModal = function () {
      addStockModal.$promise.then(addStockModal.show);
    };

    $scope.addStock = function () {
      //The following line needs to be put here again in order to retrieve the right value
      $scope.watchlist = WatchlistService.query($routeParams.listId);
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      $scope.watchlist.addStock({
        listId: $routeParams.listId,
        company: $scope.newStock.company,
        shares: $scope.newStock.shares
      });
      addStockModal.hide();
      $scope.newStock = {};
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a console.log($scope.watchlist); after both of your $scope binds to see if the data and its type match?

```
$scope.watchlist = WatchlistService.query($routeParams.listId);

 console.log($scope.watchlist);

  $scope.watchlist.addStock({
    listId: $routeParams.listId,
    company: $scope.newStock.company,
    shares: $scope.newStock.shares
  });

console.log($scope.watchlist);
```

Feel free to post the logs.

Comment: The first console log is Object {}
The second one is an exception: angular.js:10126 TypeError: $scope.watchlist.addStock is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.addStock (watchlist.js:31)
    at Parser.functionCall (angular.js:10903)
    at angular-touch.js:441
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12909)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular-touch.js:440)
    at HTMLButtonElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (jquery.js:4435)
    at HTMLButtonElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4121)

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you are calling $scope.addStock() from a modal. In which case the modal does not necessarily inherit the parent scope. It depends on which versions of everything you are using. It looks like you are using angular-strap (I looked in your bower.json). If you look in their $modal source code you will find this:

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js

var scope = $modal.$scope = options.scope && options.scope.$new() || $rootScope.$new();

So, when you are opening your modal you are creating a new scope. You might be able to access the original scope using $parent though.