# AngularJS unable to recognise function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm experiencing a similar problem as

[The $scope variable is undefined unless I forced it to retrieve from service again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914936/the-scope-variable-is-undefined-unless-i-forced-it-to-retrieve-from-service-aga)

I'm getting the below error from angular js when i'm trying to invoke a function from a service

```
TypeError: $scope.watchlist.addStock is not a function
```

This is my below controller

```
angular.module('stockDogApp')
  .controller('WatchlistCtrl', function ($scope,$routeParams,$modal,WatchlistService,CompanyService) {
    $scope.companies = CompanyService.query();
    $scope.watchlist = WatchlistService.query($routeParams.listId);
    console.log($scope.watchlist);
    $scope.stocks = $scope.watchlist.stocks;
    $scope.newStock = {};
    var addStockModal = $modal({
      scope : $scope,
      templateUrl : 'views/templates/addstock-modal.html',
      show: false
    });

    $scope.showStockModal = function(){
      addStockModal.$promise.then(addStockModal.show);
    };

    $scope.addStock = function(){
      $scope.watchlist.addStock({
        listId : $routeParams.listId,
        company: $scope.newStock.company,
        shares: $scope.newStock.shares
      });
      addStockModal.hide();
      $scope.newStock = {};
    };
```

When i log $scope.watchlist - the function does seem to be present in the object

```
Object {name: "Saklep", description: "Saklep", id: 0, stocks: Array[0]}
addStock: function(stock)
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: ""
```

This is the html for the modal window

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="$hide()">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Stock</h4>
      </div>

      <form role="form" id="add-stock" name="stockForm">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="stock-symbol">Symbol</label>
            <input type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="stock-symbol"
              placeholder="Stock Symbol"
              ng-model="newStock.company"
              bs-options="company as company.label for company in companies"
              bs-typeahead
              required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="stock-shares">Shares Owned</label>
            <input type="number"
              class="form-control"
              id="stock-shares"
              placeholder="# Shares Owned"
              ng-model="newStock.shares"
              required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit"
            class="btn btn-success"
            ng-click="addStock()"
            ng-disabled="!stockForm.$valid">Add</button>
          <button type="button"
            class="btn btn-danger"
            ng-click="$hide()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Adding the watchlist Service

```
angular.module('stockDogApp')
  .service('WatchlistService', function () {
    var loadModel = function(){
      var model = {
      watchlists : localStorage['StockDog.watchlists'] ? JSON.parse(localStorage['StockDog.watchlists']) : [],
      nextId : localStorage['StockDog.nextId'] ? parseInt(localStorage['StockDog.nextId']) : 0
    };
    _.each(model.watchlists,function(watchlist){
      _.extend(watchlist,WatchlistModel);
      _.each(watchlist.stocks,function(stock){
        _.extend(stock,StockModel);
      });
    });
    return model;
  };

  var StockModel = {
    save: function(){
      var watchlist = findById(this.listId);
      watchlist.recalculate();
      saveModel;
    }
  };

  var WatchlistModel = {
    addStock: function(stock){
      var existingStock = _.find(this.stocks,function(s){
        return s.company.symbol === stock.company.symbol;
      });
      if (existingStock){
        existingStock.shares += stock.shares;
      }else{
        _.extend(stock,StockModel);
        this.stocks.push(stock);
      }
      this.recalculate();
      saveModel();
    },
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you show the code for `WatchlistService`, but it seems like this is a `$resource`.  in this case, you didn't set `watchlist` to an instance of your `WatchListService`, you set it to equal the object returned by the `query`.

Comment: In your place I would open dev tools and put breakpoint before `addStock` function gets called. Beware that if you are using `console.log` on object browser references that object in memory thus not showing you how it looked at the moment function was called but how it looks now.

Comment: @Claies - added the service.

Comment: @GoranLepur - I'm a bit new so i dont exactly understand how adding a breakpoint would help. I tried it a while back - maybe i'm doing it wrong but i see that it shows the various functions it invokes from the angular source files. What is the next step after that?

Comment: @Kunkka, just add `var something;` on first line of your function, put breakpoint there, invoke the function with `ng-click`, after breakpoint is hit you can hover all of the variables to get the current values.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Angular-Yeoman automatically generates a controllerAs function in app.js and its the reason for the conflict

```
  .when('/watchlist/:listId', {
    templateUrl: 'views/watchlist.html',
    controller: 'WatchlistCtrl',
    // controllerAs: 'watchlist'
  })
```

commenting out controllerAs did the trick